# DC/DC converter with LM25085A and FDC5614P is not converting voltage

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck

Guys I designed a DC / DC converter from 12V-34V IN to 3.3V-OUT and I used the Power Designer from TI to help me in the designer of this converter in the website simulate everything went well. the output is the same voltage that is coming in. It is not converting the voltage.

The design of my circuit is this one.

[image]

The converter I am using is LM25085A with mosfet P-CHANNEL FDC5614P, I did as TI's Power Designer did not occur as I expected.

[UPDATE]: This is the circuit generated by TI Power Design exported to eagleCAD.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the TI Power Designer results? I see some things that are different then the Datasheet. But don't have time to thoroughly review right now.

Comment: Updated to ask with the image you requested of the design generated by TI Power Design.

Comment: Did you use the same PFET as the TI Design?

Comment: Yes, I used the same components that TI Power Design indicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what's going on, but I'd first double check the footprint of IC1 and make sure you have the pins correct.

A couple of other notes after reviewing the datasheet:
1. You are applying 12-34V to the RT pin and the application example in the datasheet shows up to 42V on that pin.  However, the absolute max on the RT pin is only 7V. You might want to reach out to TI on that one.
2. The feedback voltage is 0.9V.  Your feedback divider is configured for a 2.4V output.

Comment: I will also contact IT to help me because I did the same thing that the tool generated for me.

Comment: Team, I found the mistake that was happening the problem was that the Chinese soldered the inverted component, inverted the component and got 2.4v is not the voltage I want more is just changing the resistor 6.04kohm to 3.74kohm I have the output of 3.3v .